# How sparse matrix-indexing can be done for a matrix stored as "Compressed Sparse Row"?

Tags: c++, matrix, indexing, sparse-matrix, intel-mkl

I have my large sparse symmetric matrix stored as Compressed Sparse Row (CSR) using `Intel MKL`. For the sake of example, let's assume my symmetric sparse matrix is a `5x5`:

```
A =
    1    -1     0    -3     0
   -1     5     0     0     0
    0     0     4     6     4
   -3     0     6     7     0
    0     0     4     0    -5

values   = {1,  -1,  -3,   5,   4,   6,   4,   7,  -5}; // symmetric sparse matrix
columns  = {0,   1,   3,   1,   2,   3,   4,   3,   4}; // zero-based
rowIndex = {0,   3,   4,   7,   8,   9}; // zero-based
```

I am trying to find a submatrix of `A` given the rows and columns, e.g., `A(1:3, 2:4)`:

```
A(1:3,2:4) =
   0     0     0
   4     6     4
   6     7     0

values   = {4,   6,   4,   6,   7}; // General sparse matrix (sub-matrix is not necessarily symmetric)
columns  = {0,   1,   2,   0,   1}; // zero-based
rowIndex = {0,   0,   3,   5}; // zero-based
```

I would be grateful to know how matrix-indexing can be done. One way I can think of is to convert `CSR` to coordinate format `COO` and apply matrix-indexing and then converting it back to `CSR`, which I don't think it is an efficient way.

Could someone let me know of an efficient or a common way of sparse matrix-indexing?

Comment: You seem to know this, but it’s important to note that the result is not in general symmetric (though of course it would be easy to notice when it would retain the symmetry).

Comment: If you had a full matrix stored as CSR, it should be pretty easy. Here you have to reconstruct (explicitly of implicitly) the missing part. My first guess is that it should be similar to CSR <-> CSC format conversion and I suggest that you take a look at that algorithm (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/3b36a574dc657d1ca116f6e230be694f3de31afc/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.h#L376).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to look up values in the lower triangle by the output column (which is their row).  You can keep an index into the data for each row, since you visit the entries in column order as you progress in row order for the output.

With the expositional type

```
struct CSR {  // sometimes implicitly symmetric
  std::vector<...> vals;
  std::vector<int> cols,rowStart;
};
```

we have

```
// Return the [r0,r1) by [c0,c1) submatrix, never
// using any symmetry it might have.
CSR submatrix(const CSR &sym,int r0,int r1,int c0,int c1) {
  const int m=r1-r0,n=c1-c0;
  std::vector<int> finger(sym.rowStart.begin()+c0,sym.rowStart.begin()+c1);
  CSR ret;
  ret.rowStart.reserve(m+1);
  ret.rowStart.push_back(0);
  for(int r=0,rs=r0;r<m;++r,++rs) {
    // (Strictly) lower triangle:
    for(int cs=c0,c=0;cs<rs;++cs,++c)
      for(int &f=finger[c],f1=sym.rowStart[cs+1];f<f1;++f) {
        const int cf=sym.cols[f];
        if(cf>rs) break;
        if(cf==rs) {
          ret.vals.push_back(sym.vals[f]);
          ret.cols.push_back(c);
        }
      }
    // Copy the relevant subsequence of the upper triangle:
    for(int f=sym.rowStart[rs],f1=sym.rowStart[rs+1];f<f1;++f) {
      const int c=sym.cols[f]-c0;
      if(c<0) continue;
      if(c>=n) break;
      ret.vals.push_back(sym.vals[f]);
      ret.cols.push_back(c);
    }
    ret.rowStart.push_back(ret.vals.size());
  }
  return ret;
}
```

For large matrices, the upper triangle loop could be optimized by using a binary search to find the relevant range of `f`.

Comment: Make sure to use the corrected version; the first had typos but still compiled!